# PHP, регулярные выражения - поиск и вывод email из строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть варианты строк:

```
1)"etaliya1@mail.ru" <etaliya1@mail.ru>
2) bid@av2tomat5.ru
3) <avtomat.s2ibstrina@gmail.com>
4)  "Таня Возная" <tanya_ok77@ukr.net>
```

Необходимо взвращать только часть с почтой, т.е.:

```
1) etaliya1@mail.ru
2) bid@av2tomat5.ru
3) avtomat.s2ibstrina@gmail.com
4) tanya_ok77@ukr.net
```

Как это осуществить?

Comment: таких вопросов тут очень много. воспользуйтесь поиском: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+email

Comment: Интересно, а это реальные адреса? Если я напишу на `tanya_ok@` - там Таня письмо получит? ;)

Comment: ответа не нашел :(

Comment: не похож на дубликат

Comment: @Максим147 ответ написали, однако в будущем постарайтесь хоть как-то попробовать решить проблему. Если не получится решить задачу самостоятельно, выкладывайте Ваш код, не стесняйтесь, Вам подскажут где ошибка. Помните, что гораздо приятнее помогать если видно, что человек сам хоть как-то пытался решить задачу.

Comment: А также не забывайте закрывать вопросы (помечать как отвеченные). У нас слишком много висит незакрытых... портят статистику

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Вариант 1**. Если в строке только 1 уникальный email, как в задаче:

```
$pattern = "/[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*_`{|}~]+[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*_`{|}~\.=?]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+/i";
$text = '"etaliya1@mail.ru" <etaliya1@mail.ru>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $result);
$r = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i[0]; }, $result));
echo $r[0];
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8c4e422e3d3769cb042ec0e93f2bcffeafc9c0d)

**Вариант 2**. Если в строке возможны несколько уникальных email:

```
$pattern = "/[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*_`{|}~]+[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*_`{|}~\.=?]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+/i";
$text = '<avtomat.s2ibstrina@gmail.com>"Таня Возная" <tanya_ok77@ukr.net>';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $result);
$r = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i; }, $result));
array_walk_recursive($r, function ($item, $key) {
    echo $item."\n";
});
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6c0483c69a577c8a3738a9bf6291c0f47c48e95)

P.S.: Возможно кому-нибудь пригодится и более простой вариант `$pattern ="/[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+@[\._a-zA-Z0-9-]+/i";`, который, однако, менее строг к валидации email.

Comment: все отлично, спасибо! А как изъять текст в кавычках?

Comment: @Alex, что ваш ответ тут, что ответ в вопросе указанный как оригинал не являются верными. В обоих ответах ругулярки определяют только часть возможных email.

Comment: @Alex, http://gmailblog.blogspot.ru/2014/08/a-first-step-toward-more-global-email.html

Comment: @Alex, нелатинские символы и нет ни какого ограничения на кучу знаков, например `+` и т.д.

Comment: @Alex все отлично, спасибо! А как изъять текст в кавычках?

Comment: @Visman внесли правку в ответ, посмотрите пожалуйста.